# How configure 2 Lan cards in Windows 7/8 pc one to connect to Internet and other to Local Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, voip, windows-sbs

I am about to install a dedicated VOIP server in our office. It is a 3CX pbx system on Windows 7/8 machine. The environment currently is a Windows SBS 2011 with 8 client machines. I want to use a dedicated broadband connection for the PBX (3CX) box, but the box also needs to be accessible in the local network as we will be using IP Phones and software IP phones. How configure two network cards on PBX box, so that one will be always used to connect to our SIP host over the Internet and the other will be connected to local network accessible from other client pc to connect to the pbx system. It must be noted that currently the Windows SBS 2011 acts as the Primary Domain Controller and gateway for all the client machines. 
       I cannot use a load balancer as it will conflict and cause issues within the current setup of our SBS2011 as it is also our Exchange Server. 
Any input is much appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: So you have separate lines for broadband and VOIP? Two separate modem/routers? You could set some routes and rules on your network so that the IP phones and software VOIP ports are routed to your PBX machine (and then outbound) and all other ports are directed to your Internet gateway... You could also invest in a "dual-WAN" router and set some rules so that all VOIP traffic is directed down one connection and data down the other...

Answer (score 0):

This system needs external VOIP server or/and VOIP/SIP device. Propable if you run two different servers you can connect first to one card, second to other, but system still needs external VOIP Servers is not server only adminstration system.

read carefully http://www.3cx.com/phone-system/
supported partners http://www.3cx.com/partners/voip-providers/